# Finding controls in nested listviews

Tags: asp.net

I'm building a collapsible grouping grid using Matt Berseth's example from 
[mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html)

It has an inner listview "lvInner" nested in an outer listview "lvOuter".
  I'm trying to access a textbox in lv_Inner using

```
Protected Sub lvInner_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles lvInner.ItemDataBound

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then

     Dim tb As TextBox = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("lvOuter").FindControl("lvInner").FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
           ' Do something to TextBox1

     End If
EndSub
```

I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error on line  Dim tb.

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply do e.Item.FindControl("textbox"), e.Item is already scoped to the the proper listView.

```
Protected Sub lvInner_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles lvInner.ItemDataBound

If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then

 Dim tb As TextBox = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
       ' Do something to TextBox1

 End If
EndSub
```

Answer (score 0):

FindControl is handy, but not recursive.

If you have deep nesting of controls on a page, you might need to recursively search through the control hierarchy of the page to find the control you need.

write your own method...

C# example: (Convert using any free VBtoC# online tool)

```
public static System.Web.UI.Control FindControlFromTop(System.Web.UI.Control start, string id, System.Web.UI.Control exclude)
        {
            System.Web.UI.Control foundControl;

            if (start != null && id != null)
            {
                foundControl = start.FindControl(id);

                if (foundControl != null)
                    if(foundControl.ID.Equals(id))
                        return foundControl;

                foreach (System.Web.UI.Control control in start.Controls)
                {
                    if (control != exclude)
                        foundControl = FindControlFromTop(control, id, null);

                    if (foundControl != null)
                        if (foundControl.ID.Equals(id))
                            return foundControl;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Two things... He doesn't need recursion as e.Item is already on the inner list (look at his code)...and two, you can make your recursive method about 10 lines shorter.